# Python POST Request iteratively

Tags: python, post, request, python-requests, faker

I'm trying to make POST requests with in a loop with the following code

```
description = fake.catch_phrase()
group_id = ''
invite_only = 1 if fake.boolean(chance_of_getting_true=50) == True else 0
is_public = 1 if fake.boolean(chance_of_getting_true=50) == True else 0
title = fake.company()

payload = {description,
       group_id,
       invite_only,
       is_public,
       title}
response = requests.post(createGroup, data=(payload), headers=headers)
```

I get 
`SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: v_title cannot be null`on the server
However if I try sending the same payload  like this

```
payload = {'description': 'abc',
          'group_id': '1',
          'invite_only': '1',
          'is_public': '1',
          'title': 'someTitle'}
```

It works perfectly fine.

The question, therefore, is that can I send randomly generated data in the post call? 
If I can, how would that be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` parameter should be a dictionary, a string or a file. This, however,  is a *set*:

```
payload = {description,
       group_id,
       invite_only,
       is_public,
       title}
```

So pass a dictionary like this:

```
payload = {'description': description,
      'group_id': group_id,
      'invite_only': invite_only,
      'is_public': is_public,
      'title': title}
```

and initialise the random variables like this:

```
description = fake.catch_phrase()
group_id = ''
invite_only = int(fake.boolean(chance_of_getting_true=50))
is_public = int(fake.boolean(chance_of_getting_true=50))
title = fake.company()
```

(note the use of `int()` to convert the boolean to 1 or 0)